# How to create a file with two entries in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have two files, the first one has the date and the second one has multiple registers.
I want to create something like this:

Input File 1:

20200509

Input File 2:

0000001
0000002
0000003

Output

202005090000001
202005090000002
202005090000003

Thank u.

Comment: You create a COBOL program to read the date file, then read the register file and write the output file.  Where are you having a problem with the COBOL code?

Comment: Must you solve this with COBOL or are other solutions such as your SORT product allowed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please remove the `JCL` tag. This is not a JCL question.

Answer (score 0):

Build a record of two fields. I will not give you picture clauses.
Read file one and populate field one. (end of field one stuff).
Read file two and for each record, populate field two and write an output record.

Field one never changes?

Look into JOINKEYS (FILL?) if you get a moment and your shop has it.

And the record in File one should probably be a parameter.

Yes you will need to open and close the files, use filestat, and understand what a priming read is.

If you don't mind bad style and ANS COBOL c. 1972 see
https://github.com/mckenzm/join2files/blob/main/stackex1.cbl

(No filestat, no exception (empty file) handling.)